# Vampiric methods, type provider macros and missing runtime.VolatileObjectRef

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I am trying to write a type provider macro that uses the vampiric methods trick described [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/5967900); this is a minimal model of my implementation:

```
object DeriveFamily {
  def minimal: Any = macro DeriveFamilyMacros.minimal
}

object DeriveFamilyMacros {
  class body(tree: Any) extends StaticAnnotation

  def bodyImpl(c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val field = c.macroApplication.symbol
    val bodyAnn = field.annotations.filter(_.tree.tpe <:< typeOf[body]).head
    bodyAnn.tree.children.tail.head
  }

  def minimal(c: Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"""object Foobar { val _x = "X"; @DeriveFamilyMacros.body(Foobar._x) def x: String = macro DeriveFamilyMacros.bodyImpl }; Foobar"""
  }
}
```

This is a dumb example, the real implementation tries to use this trick to create bundles of derived typeclass instances that are accessible without reflective calls. The issue that both the real version and this one have is that they work fine if I use them in a function but they crash the compiler if I try to use them at the root of a `class` or `object` definition:

```
object Working {
  def x = {
    val foobar = DeriveFamily.minimal
    println(foobar.x)
  }

  x // Prints "X"
}

object NotWorking {
  val foobar = DeriveFamily.minimal
  println(foobar.x)
  /*
  [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last common/test:compileIncremental for the full output.
  [error] (common/test:compileIncremental) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for var Foobar$module: runtime.VolatileObjectRef in List(variable Foobar$module, value foobar, Object NotWorking, package <root>) (currentOwner= value <local NotWorking> )
  */
}
```

Any help in fixing this will be very welcome, thanks.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with macros but I remember seeing something similar. Isn't this fixed by using a class instead of an object in `minimal`?